# How to blend two pics by accessing each pixel?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, blending

For my Android application in java I need to blend 2 pics by accessing each pixel on both photos and getting the average of the pixels to give a blending effect. I know how to access each pixel but I don't know if the way I figured the average for the blending is correct.

this is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private ImageView img;
   private Bitmap bmp;
   private ImageView img2;
   private Bitmap bmp2;
   private Bitmap operation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    BitmapDrawable  abmp = (BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable();
    bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    BitmapDrawable  abmp2 = (BitmapDrawable)img2.getDrawable();
    bmp2 = abmp2.getBitmap();
}

public void blend(View v){
     operation= Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
     bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getConfig());

     for(int i=0; i<bmp.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<bmp.getHeight(); j++){
               int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
               int p2 = bmp2.getPixel(i, j);


               int r = Color.red(p);
               int g = Color.green(p);
               int b = Color.blue(p);

               int r2 = Color.red(p2);
               int g2 = Color.green(p2);
               int b2 = Color.blue(p2);

               r=(int)(r+r2)/2;
               g=(int)(g+g2)/2;
               b=(int)(b+b2)/2;

               img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(Color.alpha(p), r, g, b));
            }
     }
     img.setImageBitmap(operation); 
}
```

And the layout goes as follows:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.blendpics.MainActivity" >

   <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
  android:src="@drawable/pic1" />

          <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
  android:src="@drawable/pic2" />

      <Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:onClick="blend"
  android:text="blend" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at using RenderScript and the built in intrinsic for blend, ScriptIntrinsicBlend: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlend.html.

Comment: I was able to get the program to work with the edits I made on the page, but it runs really slowly. Any way to speed up the proccess?

Comment: You can use multiple threads, native code with multiple threads, or RenderScript.